# Trouble reading bash script output in Python

Tags: python, bash

I'm pulling my hair out trying to parse the output of the following Bash script in Python

```
#!/bin/bash
for pid in `ps aux | grep '[i]nclude' | grep -v '[i]gnore' | awk '{ print $2 }'`; do ps -p $pid -o pid= -o etime=; done
```

using os.popen like this, but it returns an empty list.

```
>>>import os
>>>p = os.popen('bin/findpid', 'r')
>>>p.readlines()
[]
```

Similarly, using subprocess.Popen also returns nothing

```
>>>import subprocess
>>>subprocess.Popen('bin/findpid', shell=True)
```

Running the script in bash outputs something like this

```
 8849    02:58:26
 9696    01:58:27
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your scripts work just fine for me. Are there any error messages? Have you made your Bash script executable?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned it works in Python 2.7 but not 2.6, which is the version I need to run it on.

Comment: So, no error messages?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one (I've used python 2.6.6, but may be you want it in the latest python 2.6):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess
import os

CMD = "bin/findpid"
p = subprocess.Popen(CMD, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print p.communicate()[0]
```

**UPDATE**: probably, first grep of findpid script needs -v too?

Comment: Sorry, still no luck in 2.6.8. Could there be something missing from the Bash script? Simple commands like 'ls' work fine using the code above.

Comment: I have removed those | grep '[i]nclude' | grep -v '[i]gnore' to try plain ps aux and it worked. Maybe -v for the first grep needed?